# Argmax of transformed RV

Tags: self-study, random-variable

Does performing a (nonlinear) transformation to a random variable, finding the value in that space that maximizes the PDF, and transforming that value back to the original space yield the same maximum as finding the value that maximizes the PDF in the original space?

Comment: What if the nonlinear transformation is a many-to-one map such as $x \mapsto x^2$? Where would the inverse map take us? to $\sqrt{y}$ or to $-\sqrt{y}$?

Comment: if transformation in one-to-one and invertible yes, why not!

Comment: Even for differentiable one-to-one transformations of continuous variables this is rarely the case.  The reason is that the PDF of the transformed variable is multiplied by the differential of the transformation, so the point of its maximum depends both on the original PDF and on the transformation.  The transformed variable could maximize its PDF at literally any value corresponding to an untransformed value with nonzero density.

Answer (score 0):

Answered in comments:

> Even for differentiable one-to-one transformations of continuous
> variables this is rarely the case.  The reason is that the PDF of the
> transformed variable is multiplied by the differential of the
> transformation, so the point of its maximum depends both on the
> original PDF and on the transformation.  The transformed variable
> could maximize its PDF at literally any value corresponding to an
> untransformed value with nonzero density.

- whuber